# Is there a way in Eclipse WindowBuilder to give one window multiple frames?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, windowbuilder

I'm trying to write a program where a user can open different menus in the same window. However, so far I only know how to make new windows. I'll use this code as an example.

```
package soGui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class SOGui {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SOGui window = new SOGui();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SOGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnLabelAdd = new JButton("Frame Add");
        btnLabelAdd.setBounds(164, 30, 92, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLabelAdd);

        btnLabelAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                makeFrame(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeFrame(ActionEvent evt) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        JLabel lblHereLabel = new JLabel("You're Here");
        lblHereLabel.setBounds(180, 127, 100, 14);
        frame2.getContentPane().add(lblHereLabel);
        frame2.getContentPane().revalidate();
        frame2.getContentPane().repaint();

        JButton btnLabelAdd2 = new JButton("Back");
        btnLabelAdd2.setBounds(164, 30, 92, 23);
        frame2.getContentPane().add(btnLabelAdd2);

        btnLabelAdd2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                frame2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It makes two different windows, one with a button called "Frame Add", and another with a button called "Back" and a label saying "You're Here". Clicking "Frame Add" makes the second window, while pressing "Back" will close the window (is setting the frame to not visible as good as closing it?)

What I want to do is instead have both screens appear on one window; when I press "Frame Add", it should move to the second screen, while pressing "Back" in the second screen will return to the first screen. Any advice would be fantastic.

Comment: You do not appear to understand what a JFrame really is. A JFrame **is** a new window. You cannot add a window to a window. Instead, consider JPanels.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've figured it out a little. Is it bad practice to have many panels in the same class? Would it be better to have each panel in its own class?

Comment: *"Is it bad practice to have many panels in the same class?"* No. *"Would it be better to have each panel in its own class?"* Now **that** would be bad practice, as it implies extending a panel for no reason.